# Is there any way to 'return early' from a Java AWS Lambda RequestStreamHandler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using API gateway to call an Java AWS Lambda via https.

I have a case where I quickly know what status I want to return from my Lambda, but I have more work to do which will not affect the status.

Is there any way of providing a status to the caller, but not ending execution of the Lambda?

I've tried:

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    writer.beginObject();
    writer.name("statusCode").value("200");
    writer.endObject();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    try {
        // this wait represents other work my Lambda is doing,
        // e.g. DB calls, requests to other webservices
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

But it still takes 10 seconds for the caller to see a status.
Is there any way to do what I want?

I would like to keep my application as simple as possible, and start as few Lambdas as possible, without making the caller wait any more than is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the status that should be returned to the caller and the other work that you have to do doesn't affect the status code nor the http response, why you want to hold the lambda execution (which is a bad idea since you're billed by execution time x memory)?

Use SNS to trigger another lambda to continue the process. It would look like:

```
caller      ->      Lambda   ->   SNS  ->  Lambda
                      |
caller <---(status)----
```

Comment: Calling another Lambda is an option, but I don't think it will save me any money -- the work will be done in one Lambda or another, and will take the same time. If I can do it all in one Lambda then my solution is simpler, and I avoid the possible overhead of starting another Lambda. Lambda startup and classloading costs around 2000ms, so doing this for *two* Lambdas on the first 'cold' request will add 4000ms of overhead.

Comment: I forgot you're using Java...that's why the cold start is painful. Have you tried creating a new thread before returning the status code?

Comment: I have -- but my reading of the docs (and perhaps I should make this a separate question) is that it isn't safe to return from handleRequest() with a background thread still running -- the JVM running the Lambda may get 'frozen' before the background thread has finished. I haven't proved that this happens though.

Comment: OT: it's interesting that as far as I can tell the expensive part of startup is classloading, not JVM startup itself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. From the point of view of architecture, it's cleaner and safer to broadcast an event to SNS and then trigger another lambda to do a specific task. Do you really need to process in the same lambda just trying to keep it simple? Another thing, do you really need to use Java? If you can, try node or python, you can keep it simple, less code and a faster cold start.

Answer (score 1):

You could wait these 10 seconds in caller method, just under the call.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that the wait represents work my Lambda will do, but which doesn't affect the status returned to the caller, and thus shouldn't delay returning a status.